# If the phone number of the contact person on my DS form changes, will that be an issue at port of entry?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I filled a phone number and address on my DS-160 during the visa application, a friend in the United States. This friend is not available any longer. Can I give the phone number of another friend? Will this be an issue at port of entry?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I give the phone number of another friend?

Yes

> Will this be an issue at port of entry?

There **can** be a problem if you are unlucky and the difference is material, although it is not typical. The information on the DS-160 is requested for a purpose and its value becomes meaningless when the information is inaccurate or outdated.

In practice of course, many times DS-160 becomes outdated example if you have a five or ten year multiple entry visa it is very possible and reasonable the person and address you will visit six years from when you acquired the visa are different from the original.

Note that US visas are quite different from UK Entry Clearance (visas). US visas only give you the right to appear at US ports of entry at which point the immigration officer determines whether to let you in or not based on his judgment. US immigration officers at ports of entry have wide latitude to deny you entry and indeed many use and abuse that latitude.

You could conceivably meet an IO who is power tripping or in a bad mood who could use that as his/her justification for an intrusive interview, wasting your time, detain you and/or subsequent deportation. We are in turbulent immigration times.

That said there is **currently no mechanism for updating the DS-160 form post interview**. If you want to be abundantly cautious, you can print out a copy and strike out the wrong information with red ink and put in the updated information to carry with you. In case the immigration officer asks where you are going and you provide the updated information, you have the hard copy in your luggage to demonstrate that yes you were forthcoming and fully intended to be truthful when asked. That said **do not volunteer information to immigration officers until you are asked**.

**REFERENCE**

My knowledge is from personal experience and binge watching numerous editions of [Homeland Security USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_Security_USA) on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JcSCxSDDTU) among others.  I was detained in the fall of 1998 at JFK for about an hour or so because the person I was visiting was different from the person on my application form.